# Condition Based On Range Between Two Numbers In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns A and B in Google Sheets. Value in Col A is 43.7 and value in Col B is 43.85. I want third column which should say "Yes" if any of the numbers between 43.7 and 43.85 is a multiple of 0.2. Here in the example 43.8 is a multiple of 0.2. If the values are 43.7 and 4.78, then it should say "No" since none of the numbers between 43.7 and 43.78 is a multiple of 0.2

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=let(a,A2*100,b,B2*100,
     if(countif(index(mod(sequence(b-a+1,1,a,1),20)),0),true,false))
```

[image]